# Contact Form on Wordpress Theme and Non-English Signs (utf-8)

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, contact-form, polish

There is a contact form already built in Wordpress Theme.

It's at the bottom of the page nikosis.mzonespace.co.uk

It's works ok, it's sending everything correctly to a good email besides non-english signs. There are just question marks when you want to type signs like ą, ę, ć, ź, ł, ó.

So it looks like this: ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?.

How to make it work? I tried hard for a an hour or two but couldn't find a solution.

Here's a contact form's code:

```
<?php 
$st_url = dirname(__FILE__);
if ( preg_match('#wp-content#isU', $st_url) ) {
    $path_to_file = explode('wp-content', $st_url);
    $path_to_wp = $path_to_file[0];
    require_once  $path_to_wp .'/wp-load.php';  
}
else {
    require_once '../../../../../../wp-load.php';  
}

function valid_email($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

if ( isset($_POST) )
{
    $_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
    $contact_name = stripslashes($_POST['fullname']);
    $contact_email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $persons_attending = stripslashes($_POST['persons_attending']);
    $wedding_ceremony = stripslashes($_POST['wedding_ceremony']);
    $regex_email = "/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix";
    if ( empty($contact_name) ) {
        $halt[] = __('Please enter your name.', 'beau');
    }
    if ( empty($contact_email) ) {
        $halt[] = __('Please enter your email.', 'beau');
    }
    elseif ( !valid_email($contact_email) ) {
        $halt[] = __('Please enter a valid email address.', 'beau');
    }
//  td


    if ( isset($halt) )
    {
        echo '<div class="st-message error">';
        echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>';
        echo @implode('<br />', $halt);
        echo '</div>';
    }
    else {

        $messages = '
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td valign="top"><b>'. __('Name', 'beau') .'</b></td><td valign="top">' . $contact_name . '</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><b>'. __('Email', 'beau') .'</b></td><td valign="top">' . $contact_email . '</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><b>'. __('Subject', 'beau') .'</b></td><td valign="top">' . $contact_subject . '</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><b>'. __('Message', 'beau')  .'</b></td><td valign="top"></td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top" colspan="2"><td valign="top">' . $contact_message . '</td></tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>';

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: " . stripslashes($contact_name) . " <" . $contact_email . ">" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Sender-IP: " . $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Priority: normal" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

        $body = utf8_decode($messages);
        if(!empty($_POST['send_to'])){
            $to = $_POST['send_to'];
        }else{
            $to=of_get_option('contact_email');
        }
        $subject = __('Contact Email From', 'beau') .': '. $contact_name;
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ) )
        {
            echo '<div class="st-message success">';
            echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>';
            echo of_get_option('contact_success', 'Your form has been submitted successfully! Thank you!');
            echo '</div>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="st-message error">';
            echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>';
            echo 'Something went wrong!';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code, I added some modifications. This one I got last time was a root file.

Still, it doesn't work:

```
    <?php 
    $st_url = dirname(__FILE__);
    if ( preg_match('#wp-content#isU', $st_url) ) {
        $path_to_file = explode('wp-content', $st_url);
        $path_to_wp = $path_to_file[0];
        require_once  $path_to_wp .'/wp-load.php';  
    }
    else {
        require_once '../../../../../../wp-load.php';  
    }

    function valid_email($str)
    {
        return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    if ( isset($_POST) )
    {
        $_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
        $contact_name = stripslashes($_POST['fullname']);
        $contact_email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
        $persons_attending = stripslashes($_POST['persons_attending']);
        $wedding_ceremony = stripslashes($_POST['wedding_ceremony']);
        $regex_email = "/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix";
        if ( empty($contact_name) ) {
            $halt[] = __('Please enter your name.', 'beau');
        }
        if ( empty($contact_email) ) {
            $halt[] = __('Please enter your email.', 'beau');
        }
        elseif ( !valid_email($contact_email) ) {
            $halt[] = __('Please enter a valid email address.', 'beau');
        }
    //  td


        if ( isset($halt) )
        {
            echo '<div class="st-message error">';
            echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>';
            echo @implode('<br />', $halt);
            echo '</div>';
        }
        else {
            $messages = '
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
            <html>
            <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" /></head>
            <body>
            <table>
                <tr><td valign="top"><b>'. __('Name', 'beau') .'</b></td><td valign="top">' . $contact_name . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top"><b>'. __('Email', 'beau') .'</b></td><td valign="top">' . $contact_email . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top"><b>'. __('Subject', 'beau') .'</b></td><td valign="top">' . $persons_attending . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top"><b>'. __('Message', 'beau')  .'</b></td><td valign="top"></td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top" colspan="2"><td valign="top">' . $wedding_ceremony . '</td></tr>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>';

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "From: " . stripslashes($contact_name) . " <" . $contact_email . ">" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Sender-IP: " . $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Priority: normal" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

            $body = utf8_decode($messages);
            if(!empty($_POST['send_to'])){
                $to = $_POST['send_to'];
            }else{
                $to=of_get_option('contact_email');
            }
            $subject = __('Contact Email From', 'beau') .': '. $contact_name;
            if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ) )
            {
                echo '<div class="st-message success">';
                echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>';
                echo of_get_option('contact_success', 'Your form has been submitted successfully! Thank you!');
                echo '</div>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div class="st-message error">';
                echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>';
                echo 'Something went wrong!';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding one more line between *<head></head>* of html in $messages--> `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. You can check my code below in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the UTF-8 Meta header,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" /> (Or)

$headers=array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. You can check my code below in the answer.